# Conversion of BVP $y'' + y' + y = 0 ,y(0) = 0, y(1) = 1$ to Integral equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, integral-equations

I was trying to convert this Boundary Value problem to an integral equation(Fredholm Integral Equation)

$y'' + y' + y = 0 ,y(0) = 0, y(1) = 1       \rightarrow (*)$

I tried but got stuck,here 
Integrating the above ODE we get

$\int_{0}^{x}y''(x) dx + \int_{0}^{x}y'(x) dx + \int_{0}^{x}y dx = c$

$y'(x) - y'(0)+y(x)- y(0) + \int_{0}^{x}y dx = c$

at $x = 1$

$y'(1) - y'(0) + y(1) - y(0) + \int_{0}^{1}y dx = c$

So $c = y'(1) - y'(0) + 1 + \int_{0}^{1}y dx$

Next substituting this value of $c$ in $(*)$,we get

$y(x) = -\int_{0}^{x}y dx - \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt + xy'(1) + x + x\int_{0}^{1}y dx$

I think I am making mistake somewhere as the form is

$y = \int_{0}^{1} K(x,t)y(t)dt$,

any help!

Answer (score 1):

Let me show that the given BVP can be rewritten as an integral equation of the form
$$
y(x)=\int_0^1K(x,t)y(t)\,dt. \tag{1}
$$
Indeed, let $K(x,t):=\lambda y_1(x)y_1(t)$, where $y_1(x)$ is a nonzero solution to the ODE
$$
y''+y'+y=0 \tag{2}
$$
satisfying$^{(*)}$ $y_1(0)=0$ and $\lambda$ is a constant to be determined. Notice that, for any $y(\cdot)$ satisfying $\int_0^1y_1(t)y(t)\,dt<\infty$, the RHS of $(1)$ is a solution to the ODE $(2)$ vanishing at $x=0$.

Its clear from the form of $K(x,t)$ that the solution to $(1)$ must be of the form $y(x)=Cy_1(x)$. However, in order that $C$ be nonzero, the value of $\lambda$ cannot be arbitrary:
\begin{align}
y(x)=Cy_1(x) &\implies Cy_1(x)=\lambda y_1(x)\int_0^1y_1(t)Cy_1(t)\,dt \\
&\implies 1=\lambda\int_0^1y_1^2(t)\,dt=:\lambda\|y_1\|_2^2 
\implies \lambda=\|y_1\|_2^{-2}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
It follows, therefore, that
$$
K(x,t)=\frac{y_1(x)y_1(t)}{\|y_1\|_2^2}. \tag{4}
$$
As a final remark, we note that the boundary condition $y(1)=1$ cannot be directly incorporated in the integral equation $(1)$, since the latter is homogeneous in $y$. However, it is trivial to verify that $y(x)=\frac{y_1(x)}{y_1(1)}$ satisfies the boundary condition at $x=1$.

---

$^{(*)}$ Explicitly, $y_1(x)=ae^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right).$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function $g\in C^2([0,1])$ with $g'(0)=0$ and $g'(x)>0$ for $x>0$ (for example $g(x)=x^2$). Multiply the equation by $g$ and integrate. You get
$$0=\int_0^x(y^{\prime\prime}g+y^{\prime}g+yg)\, dt
=y^{\prime}(x)g'(x)-\int_0^xy^{\prime}g'\, dt-y(x)g(x)\\+\int_0^x yg'\, dt+\int_0^xyg\, dt
=y^{\prime}(x)g'(x)-y(x)g'(x)\\+\int_0^xyg^{\prime\prime}\, dt-y(x)g(x)+\int_0^x yg'\, dt+\int_0^xyg\, dt.$$
Hence, 
$$y'(x)=\frac1{g'(x)}\left(-y(x)g'(x)+\int_0^xyg^{\prime\prime}\, dt-y(x)g(x)+\int_0^x yg'\, dt+\int_0^xyg\, dt\right).$$
Integrate and use Fubini's theorem (and relabel variables)
$$y(x)=\int_0^x\frac1{g'(t)}\left(-y(t)g'(t)+\int_0^tyg^{\prime\prime}\, ds-y(t)g(t)+\int_0^t yg'\, ds+\int_0^tyg\, ds\right)dt
\\=\int_0^x y(t)\left(-1-\frac{g(t)}{g'(t)}+(g^{\prime\prime}(t)+g'(t)+g(t))\int_t^x \frac1{g'(s)}\, ds\right)dt,$$
where we used the fact that $0\le s\le t\le x$.

Comment: I have not taken anywhere $c  = 0$?

Comment: you are right. See if this works.

Comment: Ok,actually what's the motivation to multiply the function $g(x)$?

Comment: well you have that $g'(0)=0$ and so when you integrate by parts the constants drop out, which was your problem from what I understood.